# MySQL change column inside LEFT JOIN expression

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to use different columns based on their values. If column A is null then use column B. 
The thing is, this is inside a `LEFT JOIN` expression:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
  novinarji
  LEFT JOIN naslovi ON novinarji.stalniNaslovId=naslovi.id
  LEFT JOIN posta ON naslovi.postaId=posta.id
WHERE
  posta.stPoste = 3000
```

I need `novinarji.stalniNaslovId` to change to `novinarji.zacasniNaslovId` when the first column is `NULL`.

I hope this is clear enough.

Thank you!

Comment: Do I understand that you are trying to join  `novinarji.stalniNaslovId` if it is not `NULL` and on `novinarji.zacasniNaslovId` if `stalniNaslovId IS NULL`?

Comment: No no, I'm trying to switch from `novinarji.stalniNaslovId` to `novinarji.zacasniNaslovId` if `novinarji.stalniNaslovId` is `NULL`

Comment: That's what I said. Are you trying to switch it in the join's `ON` clause, or in the `SELECT` list?

Comment: Ah sorry, misread your reply. In the `ON` clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not necessarily need to use onyl literal column names in a joining `ON` condition necessarily. The join's `ON` condition needs to result in a truthful boolean expression. You can therefore use [`COALESCE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) in the join condition to return the preferred column or the alternate if the preferred is `NULL`.

```
-- Careful with SELECT * in a join query...
-- better to be specific about the needed column names
SELECT *
FROM 
  novinarji
  -- COALESCE() will return stalniNaslovId if non-null, and zacasniNaslovId otherwise
  LEFT JOIN naslovi 
    ON COALESCE(novinarji.stalniNaslovId, novinarji.zacasniNaslovId) = naslovi.id
  LEFT JOIN posta 
    ON naslovi.postaId=posta.id
    -- Move this condition to the ON clause, otherwise it turns
    -- your LEFT JOIN into an INNER JOIN if filtered in the WHERE
    AND post.stPoste = 3000
```